# Shalosh Seudos - 2nd Seuda at night

Tags: halacha, meal-seudah

If one ate a second Seuda on Friday evening, does that count towards the Shalosh Seudos? Or does it have to be in the daytime?

Comment: Shouldn't be worse than eating all three in the daytime https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%A6%D7%90_%D7%90 (which only works according to some opinions; the generally accepted opinion is each has a specific spot: one at night, one in the morning, and one in the afternoon, not two in the morning nor two in the afternoon nor seemingly two at night)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general consensus of the Poskim seems to be that one should not do so, however in a time of pressing need one may do so. See sources below.

אורחות חיים (סי' רע"ד סוף ס"ק ד') – "וכן מסתברא שאינו יוצא בליל שבת אף אחר חצות לילה לאכלו את הסעודה שני' של יום כיון דקידוש ביום נמי חיובא והוא עיקר לסעודת הבקר".

הגר"א נבנצל שליט"א (אסיפת יצחק י"ח תמוז תשס"ו) – "שאלה: אם יודע שביום שבת לא יוכל לקיים ג' סעודות, האם יוצא אם יאכל ג' סעודות בלילה, ורק יקדש ביום. תשובה: כן".
עי' הגר"א נבנצל שליט"א (גם אני אודך על ענינים שונים ח"א סי' ס"ח ד"ה ושאלתי) – "אם בשעת הדחק יכול לצאת ג' סעודות ע"י שיאכל ב' סעודות בלילה, ואחד ביום, וענה לי וז"ל, תלוי במחלוקת הפוסקים אם יש לכל סעודה זמן מיוחד לה, או לא, ובלית ברירה יאכל שתים, או אף ג' בליל שבת".

מגדנות אליהו (ח"א סי' קמ"ח) – "נשאלתי במי שיודע שלא יוכל לאכול בשבת ביום רק סעודה אחת אחה"צ, האם יאכל בלילה עוד סעודה כדי להקדים ולהשלים סעודת היום. ונ"ל בס"ד דמעיקר הדין אי אפשר להקדים סעודת היום #הלילה, ומ"מ בנדון הנ"ל יעשה כן כדי לחוש לדעת כמה פוסקים שנראה מהם שאפשר להקדים."

הגריש"א זצ"ל (קונ' גלאט חכ"ג מבד"ץ שארית ישראל עמ' כ') – "שאלה: האם אפשר לאכול ב' סעודות בליל שבת. הואיל וכל מה שאוכלים סעודה ג' קודם חצות, היינו שסומכים על השיטות שאין זמן לסעודות שבת והעיקר הוא שיאכל בשבת ג' סעודות. וא"כ לכאורה א"צ דוקא שיהיה ג' סעודות ביום אלא יוכל ג"כ לחלק סעודתו בלילה, וכגון מי שקשה לו להשכים יוכל לחלק סעודת לילה לשנים. תשובה: כבוד יום עדיף. שאלה: מי שא"א לו לאכול ביום את הג' סעודות, האם יאכל בלילה כמהסעודות. תשובה: זה עדיף מכלום".

רבבות אפרים (ח"א סי' ר"ז) – "היוצא מכ"ז דאם יאכל כמה סעודות בליל שבת יקיים בזה רק מצוה של סעודה אחת. וידידי הרב ר' שלמה בלומנקרנץ שליט"א ביאר באריכות דיתכן דכן יוצא באוכל הסעודות בלילה, וא"כ בשעת הדחק ביודע בבירור שלא יוכל לאכול ביום, א"כ מה טוב דיאכל בלילה ג' סעודות ויתכן דיצא".

פסקי תשובות (דפו"ח סי' רע"ד אות י"ג) – "ומי שיודע שלא יהיה באפשרותו לאכול שני סעודות ביום, יש לדון אם כמו כן יוכל להקדים ולאכול שני סעודות בלילה, וכיון שאין הדבר מבורר להדיא בפוסקים, לא יעשה כן אלא במקום אונס גמור".

Comment: While this is correct, historically and currently, many many Jews relied and rely on the opinion that there are no fixed times for the three meals, despite that many poskim discouraged and discourage them from doing so. (Historically it was not uncommon to have two meals in the morning and now it's not uncommon to have two meals in the afternoon. I suspect two meals at night has never been common)

Comment: Source that historically Jews have relied on this?

Comment: Moz, it's apparent from all the rishonim who discuss/disapprove of those who split the morning meal in two that it was a thing that people did.